# asp.net core controller called twice for one http request

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, controller, http-get

I have an Angular 4 .NET core web site that I'm just starting to build. I made a simple controller that gets some data from a DB, which works fine. I call the controller using an http request in the ngOnInit function, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.baseURL + 'api/List/LoadLists').subscribe(result => {
        this.lists = result.json() as ListModel[];
    }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

The data comes back as expected, and the network traffic in Chrome indicates only one call was made to that location. However, if I have a breakpoint on the controller, it is hit twice.

Any idea why this would be happening? Thanks.

Comment: There is not much information to go with. But if I had to guess I would check your `startup.cs` for any custom middleware. If you have written your own check weather they interfere with the request pipeline in a bad way. Also check for double registering a middleware

Answer (score 0):

Changing the method signature on the controller worked for me (removed return type).

From (pseudocode):

`[HttpPost]
[Route("customer")]
public async Task<CustomerDto> AddCustomer([FromBody]CustomerDto data)`

To:

`[HttpPost]
[Route("customer")]
public async Task AddCustomer([FromBody]CustomerDto data)`